# ConfigServerHealthIndicator - Health check failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have `native` and `vault` profiles enabled in config server.

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  profiles:
    active: native, vault
```

Because of this the actuator endpoints are not working. How can I have the actuator endpoints up and working? I get the following error in console after config service starts up.

```
2022-11-28 04:00:17.667  WARN [RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.0.102] org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator - Health check failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:313) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:329) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:324) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:292) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.getHeader(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.getWatchState(AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentRepository.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6ae93c63.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.vault.SpringVaultEnvironmentRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f6a7caa.findOne(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:94) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:41) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:78) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:97) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

I have added `spring-boot-starter-actuator` as a dependency. Also have the following configurations enabled in application.yml file.

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    export:
      simple:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/"
      exposure:
        include: info, health
```

`spring-boot-starter-parent` version used `2.7.6`, `spring-cloud-starter-config` and `spring-cloud-config-server` are on `3.1.5`